# Two table cells instead of one angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'll try to explain my problem as simple as I can. I have something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="ordinate in ordinatesX">{{ordinate.ordinateLabel}}</th>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

This is just a small peace of my table but it is the problematic one. My ordinate object has an attribute `abstract`. When the `abstract` is set to `true` and DOM to make two `th` like this:

```
<th>{{ordinate.ordinateLabel}}</th><th></th>
```

So the first `th` is writing ordinate label and the second `th` needs to be empty.
But when the `abstract` is set to `false` I need only one `th` like this:

```
<th>{{ordinate.ordinateLabel}}</th>
```

I've tried something with the simplest custom directive like this:

```
.directive('ngTest', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            template: '<th></th><th></th>'
        }
});
```

But even this wasn't working because of the problem with the `replace: true` and root element being `tr`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine [ng-repeat-start](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and [ng-if](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

ng-if will not insert element in DOM.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat-start="ordinate in ordinatesX">{{ordinate.ordinateLabel}}</th><th ng-if="ordinate.abstract" ng-repeat-end></th>
    </tr>   
</table>
```